# I can't remove genymotion. Nothing works

Tags: gnome-terminal, software-uninstall, genymotion

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; I'm new to Linux. I've installed Genymotion a long time ago together with Virtual Box, in order to run an Android emulation on my desktop. Now, I decided to remove them. I successfully uninstalled Virtual Box, but Genymotion is still there no matter what I try to get rid of it.

The software created three items which remain in my desktop: 'genymotion-log.zip', 'genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin' and a folder called 'genymotion', full of files and subfolders.

None of the commands below work. The terminal says the directory or package can't be find or that the command is invalid.

`(sudo) apt-get --purge remove genymotion`

`(sudo) ./genymotion-2.7.2_x64.bin --uninstall`

`(sudo) ./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall`

`/home/egavs/Desktop/genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall`

(egavs in my Ubuntu username)

Also, Genymotion is absent on Ubuntu Software Center. If I type 'genymotion' in the Ubuntu search and right-click its icon, there is an option to launch it, but no other to remove it. But Genymotion can't be launched, since it depends on Virtual Box.

Genymotion's icons and folders are still there and nothing I try is removing them. Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I found the official solution from the Genymotion website:
Remove all virtual devices using from Genymotion (unfortunately, you deleted VirtualBox, so simply delete the disk images within your installation folder.

Delete Genymotion installation directory by running 
`sudo rm -r ~/genymotion` (if installed in your home directory).

Delete Genymotion data directories by running

`sudo rm -fr ~/.Genymobile ~/.config/Genymotion.`

Change the folder paths based on where they are. Show hidden files with Ctrl-H in Nautilus.

It should be perfectly safe to remove the .bin files on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks. But none of these commands work :( I'm afraid to use this last method, since you said it's not recommended.

Comment: Edited, upvote if this helped. Good luck.

Comment: It apparently worked. I can find no remaining Genymotion icons, folders or files. Thanks a lot! But is there any way to check if it was definitely uninstalled?

Comment: That is the official Genymotion method, so yes, it should be fully uninstalled.